# I'm new to Java Swing, and coding in general and a code I wrote today is having an odd glitch involving the button.doClick() method.

Tags: java, swing

If someone could review my code for me, give me some pointers etc, I would be very grateful!
So in this game in case you've never played Mastermind, basically three colours are hidden in a specific order and the user has to guess what they are out of four possible colours. The code appears to work fairly well, even though it is currently unfinished, however an odd glitch occurs once the user wins. When the player properly guesses the three hidden colours, they are prompted to press the "Play again" button, which is then supposed to reset the game, which it appears to do, however once the user inputs another colour into the JTextFields designated to do so, the words last entered in those fields are revealed. I have implemented a small line that displays the word "working" on a nearby JLabel to show that the doClick() methods are activating, but the reset button doesn't work as intended, even though the newGame button does. Its an odd glitch, if anyone has a fix or reason for this glitch or any other general improvements you would make my day!

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.ComponentOrientation;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.Insets;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;


public class Summative2 extends JFrame {
    static int guessNum;
    static String colourGuess[] = new String[3];
    static String colourArgument;
    static int[] solution = new int[3];
    public Summative2() {
        for (int x=0;x<3;x++)
        {
            solution[x] = solution();   //Setting the solution for the first game
        }
        displayIntro();     //Activating the intro screen to start the program

    }
    public void displayIntro()
    {
        JPanel introPanel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        this.getContentPane().add(introPanel);

        GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();    //The variable name being defined for the layout's constraints
        introPanel.setComponentOrientation(ComponentOrientation.LEFT_TO_RIGHT); //Setting the orientation of the Grid layout

        c.insets = new Insets(2,2,2,2); //Basic spacing and anchoring
        c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.CENTER;
        JLabel welcome = new JLabel("Welcome to MASTERMIND");
        c.ipady = 40;
        c.gridx = 1;        //Large welcome label, introducing the game
        c.gridy = 0;
        c.gridwidth = 3;
        introPanel.add(welcome, c);
        c.ipady = 0;    //Resetting the characteristics of the components back to normal after the large intro message
        c.gridwidth = 1;

        JButton start = new JButton ("Start");
        c.gridx = 1;    //The start button
        c.gridy = 1;
        introPanel.add(start, c);

        JLabel space = new JLabel(" ");
        c.gridx = 2;
        c.ipadx = 10;       //Space between the Start and Rules buttons
        c.gridy = 1;
        introPanel.add(space, c);
        c.ipadx= 0;

        JButton rulesButton = new JButton("Rules");
        c.gridx = 3;        //Rules button
        c.gridy = 1;
        introPanel.add(rulesButton, c);

        rulesButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                introPanel.setVisible(false);
                displayRules("intro");  //Makes the intro panel invisible and activates the rules panel, along with an argument that tells the displayRules method to return the user to the intro screen when they press back after reading the rules
            }

        });
        start.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                introPanel.setVisible(false);       //Makes the intro invisible and starts the main game.
                displayGame(false);
            }

        });
    }

    public void displayRules(String previousScreen) {       
        JPanel rulesPanel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        GridBagConstraints r = new GridBagConstraints();
        rulesPanel.setComponentOrientation(ComponentOrientation.LEFT_TO_RIGHT);
        this.getContentPane().add(rulesPanel);

        JTextField rulesText = new JTextField("insert rules here");
        rulesText.setEditable(false);
        r.gridx = 0;
        r.gridy = 0;
        r.gridwidth = 3;
        r.ipady=100;    //Big rules text box`                       NOT YET FINISHED    
        r.ipadx = 100;
        rulesPanel.add(rulesText, r);
        r.gridwidth =1;
        r.ipadx=1;
        r.ipady=1;

        JButton backFromRules = new JButton("Back");
        r.gridx = 2;                //back button
        r.gridy=1;
        rulesPanel.add(backFromRules, r);

        backFromRules.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                rulesPanel.setVisible(false);
                if (previousScreen.compareTo("intro")==0)           //When the user presses the back button they are returned to the screen from which they activated the rules screen
                {
                displayIntro();
                }
                if (previousScreen.compareTo("game")==0)
                displayGame(false);             
            }

        });
    }
    public void displayGame(boolean restart)
    {   
        JPanel gamePanel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        GridBagConstraints g = new GridBagConstraints();
        gamePanel.setComponentOrientation(ComponentOrientation.LEFT_TO_RIGHT);
        this.getContentPane().add(gamePanel);

        g.anchor=GridBagConstraints.WEST;

        g.weightx =1;

        int coloursY = 0;
        JButton redButton = new JButton("Red");
        redButton.setBackground(Color.RED);     //the red button, which is red
        g.gridx= 0;
        g.gridy=coloursY;
        gamePanel.add(redButton, g);

        JButton greenButton = new JButton("Green");
        greenButton.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
        g.gridx = 1;                            //The green button, which is green
        g.gridy = coloursY;
        gamePanel.add(greenButton, g);

        JButton blueButton = new JButton("Blue");
        blueButton.setBackground(Color.CYAN);               //The blue button, which is cyan
        g.gridx =2;
        g.gridy=coloursY;
        gamePanel.add(blueButton, g);

        JButton yellowButton = new JButton("Yellow");
        yellowButton.setBackground(Color.yellow);           //The yellow button which is yellow
        g.gridx=3;
        g.gridy=coloursY;
        gamePanel.add(yellowButton, g);

        g.weightx=0;
        g.weighty=0;


        JLabel firstGuess = new JLabel("First Block Guess:");//The label for the first guess in each guessing sequence, followed by labels for the seconds and third
        g.gridx = 0;
        g.gridy=1;
        g.gridwidth = 2;
        gamePanel.add(firstGuess, g);

        JLabel secondGuess = new JLabel("Second Block Guess:");
        g.gridx = 0;
        g.gridy=2;
        gamePanel.add(secondGuess, g);

        JLabel thirdGuess = new JLabel("Third Block Guess:");
        g.gridx = 0;
        g.gridy=3;
        gamePanel.add(thirdGuess, g);

        JTextField guessOne = new JTextField("");       //The text field where the user can enter thier guess for the first colour in a possible solution
        guessOne.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(50,24));
        g.gridx = 2;
        g.gridy = 1;
        guessOne.setComponentOrientation(ComponentOrientation.LEFT_TO_RIGHT);
        gamePanel.add(guessOne, g);

        JTextField guessTwo = new JTextField("");           //Second colour
        guessTwo.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(50,24));
        g.gridx = 2;
        g.gridy = 2;
        gamePanel.add(guessTwo, g);

        JTextField guessThree = new JTextField("");         //Third
        guessThree.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(50,24));
        g.gridx = 2;
        g.gridy = 3;
        gamePanel.add(guessThree, g);

        JButton update = new JButton();//The update button, which doesn't exist but I used it as a type of repeatable method for whenever the user presses a colour button

        JLabel GOneIndicator = new JLabel("<--");       //These arrows move when the user presses a colour button, letting them know where their next colour guess will be applied
        g.gridx = 3;
        g.gridy = 1;
        gamePanel.add(GOneIndicator, g);

        JLabel GTwoIndicator = new JLabel("<--");
        g.gridx = 3;
        g.gridy = 2;
        gamePanel.add(GTwoIndicator, g);
        GTwoIndicator.setVisible(false);

        JLabel GThreeIndicator = new JLabel("<--");
        g.gridx = 3;
        g.gridy = 3;
        gamePanel.add(GThreeIndicator, g);
        GThreeIndicator.setVisible(false);

        g.gridwidth = 2;
        g.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;

        JButton submitButton = new JButton("SUBMIT"); //Submit guess
        g.gridx = 0;
        g.gridy = 4;
        gamePanel.add(submitButton, g);

        JButton resetButton = new JButton("Reset");     //Reset your guess JTextFields
        g.gridx = 2;
        g.gridy = 4;
        gamePanel.add(resetButton, g);

        JButton newGame = new JButton("New Game");      //Generates a new solution and presses the reset button
        g.gridx = 0;
        g.gridy = 5;
        gamePanel.add(newGame, g);

        JButton rulesButton = new JButton("Rules");
        g.gridx = 2;                        //Displays the rules
        g.gridy = 5;
        gamePanel.add(rulesButton, g);

        submitButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                String guess[] = new String[3];
                boolean proper = true;
                guess[0]= guessOne.getText();
                guess[1] = guessTwo.getText();
                guess[2] = guessThree.getText();
                for (int y = 0;y<3;y++)
                {
                    if ((guess[y].compareToIgnoreCase("blue")!=0) && (guess[y].compareToIgnoreCase("red")!=0) && (guess[y].compareToIgnoreCase("green")!=0) && (guess[y].compareToIgnoreCase("yellow")!=0))
                    {
                        proper = false; //If one of the text fields had a word that wasn't one of the colours available for guessing, the user will be told so.
                    }
                }
                if (proper)
                check(guess);//If everything was in order, check the guess against the solution
                else
                errorWindow();//Otherwise, nope
            }
        });

        resetButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {//Sets all of the textFields blank, the guessnumber to 1 and makes the fiirst arrow appear as if it were the first guess.
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                guessOne.setText("");
                guessTwo.setText("");
                guessThree.setText("");
                guessNum=1; 
                GOneIndicator.setVisible(true);
                GTwoIndicator.setVisible(false);
                GThreeIndicator.setVisible(false);
            }
        });

        newGame.addActionListener(new ActionListener () {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {//Clicks the reset and generates a new solution set.
                resetButton.doClick();
                for(int d=0;d<3;d++)
                    solution[d]= solution();                
            }
        });

        if (restart)//If this screen was generated from the user pressing the play again button after winning, the game should be automatically reset and new solutions generated, this is bugging out somehow.
        {
            newGame.doClick();
            GOneIndicator.setText("working");
            resetButton.doClick();
            restart=false;
        }

        rulesButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {//more rules display that isnt finished yet
                gamePanel.setVisible(false);
                displayRules("game");
            }
        });

        update.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {//When a colour button is pressed, the next guess Field is filled in order, depending on the last one that was filled
                colourGuess[guessNum-1] = colourArgument;
                if (guessNum ==1 ){
                    guessOne.setText(colourArgument);
                    GOneIndicator.setVisible(false);
                    GTwoIndicator.setVisible(true);
                    guessNum++;
                }
                else if (guessNum ==2){
                    guessTwo.setText(colourArgument);
                    GTwoIndicator.setVisible(false);
                    GThreeIndicator.setVisible(true);
                    guessNum++;
                }
                else if (guessNum==3){
                    guessThree.setText(colourArgument);
                    GThreeIndicator.setVisible(false);
                    GOneIndicator.setVisible(true);
                    guessNum = 1;
                }
            }

        });


        redButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) { //Red is put into the next guess slot0
                colourArgument = "Red";
                update.doClick();
            }

        });

        blueButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {//Then blue 
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                colourArgument = "Blue";
                update.doClick();
            }
        });

        yellowButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {//Or yellow
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                colourArgument = "Yellow";
                update.doClick();
            }
        });

        greenButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {//or green
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                colourArgument = "Green";
                update.doClick();
            }
        });
    }
    public void check(String guess[])
    {
        JFrame checkWindow = new JFrame();
        checkWindow.setSize(300,100);
        JPanel pane = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
        checkWindow.getContentPane().add(pane);             //This is all to set up the initial window generally, and activate the layouts and whatnot

        GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();    
        pane.setComponentOrientation(ComponentOrientation.LEFT_TO_RIGHT); 
        checkWindow.setVisible(true);

        c.insets = new Insets(2,2,2,2);

        int numGuess[] = new int[3];    //
        int colourCount=0;
        int positionCount=0;        //Converts the information in the textFields to numbers which can be more easily compared
        for (int x =0;x<3;x++)
        {
            if (guess[x].compareToIgnoreCase("red")==0)
            {
                numGuess[x] = 1;
            }
            if (guess[x].compareToIgnoreCase("blue")==0)
            {
                numGuess[x] = 2;
            }
            if (guess[x].compareToIgnoreCase("green")==0)
            {
                numGuess[x] = 3;
            }
            if (guess[x].compareToIgnoreCase("yellow")==0)
            {
                numGuess[x] = 4;
            }               
        }

        for (int z=0;z<3;z++) //Runs through the inputs compared to the solution, finding out how many of the colours were correct, and any of those colours that were in the correct positions
        {
            boolean guessed = false;
            for (int k=0;k<3;k++)
            {
                if (solution[z] == numGuess[k])
                {
                    guessed = true;
                }
            }
            if (solution[z] == numGuess[z])
            positionCount++;
            if (guessed)
            colourCount++;          
        }

        c.fill=GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        c.anchor = GridBagConstraints.CENTER;
        if (positionCount ==3)  //If all three positions are correct the user wins
        {
            JLabel colours = new JLabel(guess[0] + ", " + guess[1] + ", " + guess[2] + " is correct!");
            c.gridx=0;
            c.gridy=0;
            pane.add(colours, c);

            JLabel winner = new JLabel("You WIN!");
            c.gridx=0;
            c.gridy=1;
            pane.add(winner, c);

            JButton playAgain = new JButton("Play Again");
            c.gridx=0;
            c.gridy=1;
            pane.add(playAgain, c);

            playAgain.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {//Glitch causing button
                    for(int x=0;x<3;x++)
                    {
                        solution[x] = (int) (Math.random()*4)+1;
                    }
                    checkWindow.dispose();
                    displayGame(true);                  
                }
            });
        }
        else
        {

        JLabel labelOne = new JLabel(guess[0] + ", " + guess[1] + ", " +guess[2]);//If the user doesn't win, how many correct colours and positions they had are displayed
        c.gridx = 0;
        c.gridy = 0;
        pane.add(labelOne, c);      

        JLabel colourMessage = new JLabel("You had " + colourCount + " correct colours.");
        c.gridx=0;
        c.gridy=1;
        pane.add(colourMessage, c);

        JLabel positionMessage = new JLabel("You had " + positionCount + " in the correct positions");
        c.gridx=0;
        c.gridy=2;
        pane.add(positionMessage, c);
        }

    }
    public void errorWindow()
    {
        JFrame checkWindow = new JFrame();
        checkWindow.setSize(200,100);
        JPanel pane = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());//This window is displayed if the user inputs impossible values for their colour guesses
        checkWindow.getContentPane().add(pane);

        GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();    
        pane.setComponentOrientation(ComponentOrientation.LEFT_TO_RIGHT); 
        checkWindow.setVisible(true);

        JLabel whoops = new JLabel("Try Again with valid colours.");
        c.gridx=0;
        c.gridy=0;
        pane.add(whoops, c);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Summative2 frame = new Summative2(); //main method making the JFrame work properly
        guessNum = 1;
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
        frame.setSize(300, 225);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }
    public static int solution()
    {
        return (int) (Math.random()*4+1);//Solution method returning random numbers between 1 and 4 for solutions.
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Every time you call the `check()` method, you're creating new `ActionListener` and registering it on the `playAgain` button.

This way, you get lots and lots of action listeners, and once the user finally clicks the `playAgain` button, they are all called, one by one.

You can see that yourself by setting a breakpoint inside the `ActionListener` code and debugging the application.

The solution would be to move that logic out of the `check()` method, to someplace where the form is initialized.

Comment: Sorry, where exactly is the form initialized? I'm not good with the jargon, but my best guess is that you mean I should take the check() method and simply put its contents more or less inside the displayGame() method?

Comment: In your case the form is initialized in the constructor - it calls `displayIntro()`, which bulds initial UI. The `ActionListener`s should be registered only once, and not in the method called from other `ActionListener`s - to avoid registering multiple listeners on the single button.